# C Structs--error: parameter name omitted

Tags: c, compiler-construction, parameters, struct, arguments

I am receiving the following error for the following code:

```
kernel/proc.c: In function ‘getpinfo’:
kernel/proc.c:495: error: parameter name omitted
```

The code is as follows:

```
int 
getpinfo(struct pstat *)
{
}
```

Can you please tell me what I am missing about the struct or the code?

Comment: getpinfo(struct pstat \*) - it says "pointer to a struct pstat but in C when you declare/define functions you need to name your parameters as well, like this: int add(int a, int b); a and b are names, int is a type; in your example struct pstat* is  type and the name is missing (which is exactly what the compiler tells you) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
     int 
     getpinfo(struct pstat *)   
      {
      }
```

Did not given any parameter Name.

`Function definition should contain List of parameters, with valid type and parameters names.where as in declarations parameter Names are optional`

This should be

```
     int 
     getpinfo(struct pstat *some_name)
       {
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

A parameter to a function requires both a *type* and a *name*, but `struct pstat *` is only a *type*.

You can give it any name you like:

```
int 
getpinfo(struct pstat * s)
{
}
```